# Low level string manipulation functions in C

Tags: c, strings, c99

I'm working with a legacy program that does a bunch of markup manipulation, some of it higher-level and specific to the proprietary markup, some of it lower level string stuff.

I rewrote and documented the customized low level stuff (and used string.h stuff where applicable). I'm not not usually a C-coder, but I'm trying to learn.

- Am I duplicating core functionality of a standard library?
- Am I following conventions/best practices?
- Is the code efficient?

#### string_plus.h

```
/**
 * @file
 *
 * A small library of additional low level string manipulation functions. If any
 * functionality is duplicated from any of the normal libraries, it is due to
 * ignorance.
 */

#ifndef STRING_PLUS_H
#define STRING_PLUS_H

#include <string.h>

/**
 * Returns 1 if the front of @p text matches @p search_key, else 0.
 */
int begins_with(char const *text, char const *search_key);

/**
 * Condenses a string buffer by sliding all contents at @p p2 down to @p p1. In
 * other words, anything in between @p p1 and @p p2 is deleted. Returns @p p1.
 */
char *condense_buffer(char *p1, char *p2);

/**
 * Modifies @p text, removing all occurrences of @p c. Returns @p text.
 */
char *remove_char_occurrences(char *text, char const c);

/**
 * Inserts @p content into a buffer at @p p by shifting the buffer's data by @p
 * content's size. Returns a pointer at the end of the newly modified buffer.
 *
 * @warning Caller is responsible for guarding against a buffer overrun.
 */
char *insert_content(char *p, char const *content);

#endif /* Header load-once guard clause */
```

#### string_plus.c

```
#include "string_plus.h"

int begins_with(char const *text, char const *search_key) {
  int result = 1;
  while (*search_key != '\0' && (result = *search_key++ == *text++));
  return result;
}

char *condense_buffer(char *p1, char *p2) {
  while (*(p2-1) != '\0') *p1++ =*p2++;
  return p1;
}

char *remove_char_occurrences(char *text, char const c) {
  char *lead = text;
  char *tail = text;
  while (*lead != '\0') {
    while (*lead == c) ++lead;
    *tail++ = *lead++;
  }
  *tail = *lead;
  return text;
}

char *insert_content(char *p, char const *content) {
  int content_len = strlen(content);
  for (char *end = p + strlen(p); end >= p; end--) *(end + content_len) = *end;
  while (*content != '\0') *p++ = *content++;
  return p;
}
```

#### test functions

```
void test_begins_with() {
  Assert(begins_with("Theory", "The") == 1);
  Assert(begins_with("theory", "The") == 0);
  Assert(begins_with("T", "The") == 0);
  Assert(begins_with("Theory", "") == 1);
}

void test_condense_buffer() {
  char buff[] = "hello world";
  condense_buffer(&buff[7], &buff[10]);
  Assert(strcmp("hello wd", buff) == 0);
}

void test_remove_char_occurrences() {
  char s1[] = "hello world";
  Assert(strcmp("hello world", remove_char_occurrences(s1, 'x')) == 0);

  char s2[] = "hello world";
  Assert(strcmp("heo word", remove_char_occurrences(s2, 'l')) == 0);
}

void test_insert_content() {
  char buff[50] = "hello world";
  char *p = insert_content(&buff[5], "BRAVENEW");
  Assert(strcmp("helloBRAVENEW world", buff) == 0);
  Assert(strcmp(" world", p) == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `condense_buffer` is equivalent to `strcpy`. If you still wish to implement it, use an idiomatic `C` construct:

  ```
      while ((*p1++ = *p2++) != 0)
          {}
  ```
- `begins_with` is equivalent to `strncmp(text, key, strlen(key))`. It might be argued though that `strncmp` approach requires a call to `strlen` and thus incurs performance penalty.
- Do put the loop body on a separate line. Do not omit curly braces even for one-liners:

  ```
     for (char *end = p + strlen(p); end >= p; end--) {
         *(end + content_len) = *end;
     }
  ```

Comment: 1. They are only equivalent because `p2` is a pointer somewhere into the middle of a c-string. That's for an unreliable and unintuitive precondition. 2. Not sure how the need for `strlen` in `strncmp` could be argued. Any hint? 3. Forcing braces for single statements has no advantages. Giving the body it's own line now, sure.

Comment: @Deduplicator 1. I ain't get it. The code _is_ identical. 2. Because `strncmp` needs length. 3. It has so many advantages that here is not a place to discuss them, and no disadvantages whatsoever.

Comment: 1. Start `condense_buffer` at the beginning of a string. 2. Oops, I dropped a thought there. 3. Yep, writing more is always so much better. There should be at least one post on programmers where the camps get into it.

Comment: Yes! `condense_buffer` is equivalent to `strcpy`, I had not realized it. After reanalyzing my codebase, there's no reason why I should keep `condense_buffer` around. Thanks! That was the sanity check I needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `strncmp` too. I'm keeping `begins_with`, more for semantic reasons than performance, but I did like your idea.

Answer (score 1):

Three things strike me when reading through your code:

- *Loop bodies not indented on separate lines* – Quite a few times in this short code segments I wondered why you don't indent stuff when using `while`. Then I saw that you had loop bodies after the `while` condition. Do please shift *all* of these down a line, and always include braces. Your current style will give you issues (read: bugs) sooner or later!
- *Very limited error handling* – You put a lot of trust on the code calling your code as you always expect strings to be `\0`-terminated, and have allocated enough memory for your operations to complete. Kind of typical for C, but still not good practice
- *Missing name convention* – If you look at the documentation they are consistent in naming of arguments. I.e. in `string.h` you see loads of `src`, `dst`, `c`, `n` which due to their consistency are easily understood. Your names are lacking a little in this regard, and this makes it harder to understand what is happening

Comment: 1. Braceophilia is a recognized disease some people suffer from. Heal it, don't spread it. 2. Well, adding an assert at the start to weed out programmer-error in debug-mode might be a good idea. Anything more is just playing to C's weaknesses instead of strengths.

Comment: @deduplicator, in this case he does need to add braces, or seriously work with moving code away from after while/if.  If not Murphy will come visit him very soon

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Indeed, I agree that `for (char *end = p + strlen(p); end >= p; end--) *(end + content_len) = *end;` needs a line break (and of course, braces!). But I'm comfortable with shorter one-lines: `while (*lead == c) ++lead;`. For these low level functions, I think the unit-test approach helps keep Murphy at bay more than extra line breaks.